# Creating an input file in c++

Tags: c++, file-io

I couldn't figure out why

`std::ifstream dbf = ("db.txt")` gives an error

but `std::ifstream dbf ("db.txt")` doesnt

Thank you I just wish to understand this

Comment: what does the error message say?

Comment: conversion from 'const char [7]' to non scalar type 'std::ifstream' requested

Comment: Why do you expect those to do the same thing? Do you understand the different things that parentheses mean, such as in `sqrt(4)` and `a = (b+c)*d`?

Comment: The bracets in your first example has no effect, and I think it would work, if the fstream constructor would be not explicit.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::ifstream dbf ("db.txt")
```

Is the syntax for **explicitly calling a constructor**.

`"db.txt"` is passed, as a single parameter, to construct a `std::ifstream`.

```
std::ifstream dbf = ("db.txt")
```

Is the syntax for **converting** `"db.txt"` to a `std::ifstream`.

This will not compile, because `std::ifstream` is not designed to support **implicit** conversions from string literals.

While constructors can be designed to also support implicit conversions, this constructor call [has been marked `explicit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream).